# Calculating the distinct number of product categories per client in power bi

Tags: count, nested, dax

[Data and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0QLs.png) Dear Stackoverflow members;

I have a question that I don't seem to figure out.
Apologies if it is a basic question (I'm rather new to dax).

I have customer sales by year and product category.
I need a **DAX measure** that can calculate the number of unique product categories per year (or context period ex. YTD, Rolling 12 months and other filteres) per customer

The data is:

Year    Date    ClientID    ProductCategory Sales
2019    Aug-19  1   Bikes   100.00
2019    Aug-19  1   Computer200.00
2019    Aug-19  1   Radio   500.00
2019    Sep-19  2   Bikes   200.00
2019    Sep-19  2   Radio   300.00
2019    Oct-19  1   Bikes   100.00
2019    Oct-19  2   Radio   200.00
2019    Oct-19  2   Radio   500.00
2019    Oct-19  2   Radio   200.00
2019    Nov-19  1   Computer300.00
2019    Nov-19  2   Bikes   100.00
2019    Dec-19  1   Bikes   200.00
2019    Dec-19  1   Computer200.00
2019    Dec-19  2   Bikes   300.00
2020    Jan-20  1   Radio   100.00
2020    Jan-20  1   Computer200.00
2020    Feb-20  2   Bikes   500.00
2020    Feb-20  1   Radio   100.00
2020    Feb-20  2   Computer200.00
2020    Mar-20  1   Bikes   500.00
2020    Mar-20  2   Radio   200.00
2020    Mar-20  2   Radio   300.00

and the desired output is:
|Year   |Client |NumDistinctProductCategories   |Sales
|2019   |1             |3                       |1600
|2019   |2             |2                       |1800
|2020   |1             |3                       | 900
|2020   |2             |3                       |1200

And
|Year   |Num DistinctProductCategories  |Sales
|2019   |3                              |1600
|2019   |2                              |1800
|2020   |3                              | 900
|2020   |3                              |1200

This last table would allow me to create a bar chart.

I gather that this will be a nested count and sum but I can't figure it out.
Could you please help?

Thanks

Comment: I'm new to Stackoverflow, so apologies if this message is a bit on the rough side.

Comment: Have you tried the simple `NumDistinctProductCategories = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ProductCategory]))`?

Answer (score 0):

try out these two measures

```
   count =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( tbl[ProductCategory] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( tbl, tbl[Year], tbl[ClientID], tbl[ProductCategory] )
    )

sum =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( tbl[Sales] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( tbl, tbl[Year], tbl[ClientID], tbl[ProductCategory] )
)
```

Comment: Thanks smpa01. Those work for the table of client id and number of categories. Then I need another step which is to get a table with number of categories bought and number of clients in each category. The last table in my example. This is where I am getting truly stuck.

Comment: Also, is the result of the measure (the distinct count of categories) should be the axis of a chart